# Angular 6 Reactive Form: How do I fix TypeError: formDirective.resetForm() is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on an app, which allows allows users to input an event postcode and place a marker of the event on a map using GoogleMaps API. In order to do this I need to convert the user postcode to lat/lng and then upload this data to the server.

The application works fine, but with one draw back. In order for it to work I have to disable formDirective.resetForm(), otherwise it throws an error:

TypeError: formDirective.resetForm() is not a function.

So what I'm left with is an app, which, functionally, works great in terms of rendering markers to the map, but has an ugly interface, which does not reset after submitting the form.

Is there an alternative method available which allows me to reset the form without incurring this error? I thought about placing the geocoding function in a separate method and then passing the resulting lat/lng data to onAddPost(). But the onAddPost() function expects a formDirective argument, so I'm not sure how to get around this.

Any guidance or advice, most appreciated.
Thank you.

event-post HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form" #formDirective="ngForm" (submit)="onAddPost(form, formDirective)">

<!-------- HTML ---------!>

</form>
```

Typescript file

```
async onAddPost(formDirective: FormGroupDirective) {

/****  Convert user postcode to lat/lng using geocoding service ********/

  this.latLngPostcode = undefined;
  const location = await 
  this.geocodeService.geocodeAddress(this.form.value.postcode).toPromise();

  this.latLngPostcode = {
    lat: location.lat,
    lng: location.lng
  };

console.log('Postcode successfully converted to LAT/LNG: ',
this.latLngPostcode.lat + ' ' + this.latLngPostcode.lng);

/******* Upload form data to postService ******************************/

  if (this.form.invalid) {
    return;
  }
    this.postsService.addPost(
      this.form.value.content,
      this.form.value.title,
      this.form.value.datePicker,
      this.form.value.postcode,
      this.form.value.image,
      this.latLngPostcode.lat,
      this.latLngPostcode.lng);
    this.form.reset();
   formDirective.resetForm(); /* <--- TypeError:formDirective.resetForm is not a function */
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're working with `FormGroupDirective`. You don't provide the context where `onAddPost` is called. Anyway: `resetForm` is a method of `NgForm` instance, not of `NgFormDirective` instances.

Comment: How do you retrieve the `formDirective` ?

Comment: @Codo there is one `resetForm` for [FormGroupDirective](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective#resetform) that you can use to reset the validators.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my original post with the first line of the event-post HTML file which shows how formDirective is being passed as an argument to onAddPost. NOTE: formDirective.resetForm() works fine until I introduce the geocoding code. This was a modification I added so postcodes can be converted to lat/lng and stored on the server. Again, any help would be appreciated. Thanks jocactus and Codo for taking the time out to look into my problem.